# get data from HTML without using django form template

Tags: python, django

Is there a way in Django to get the data from HTML without using `django  forms template` in html. The reason is we are two different Developers , one who works on Frontend ui design and the other django coder.

So if he just gives me html and css files, i won't be able to just use it, unless i add form template in HTML substituting his code.

i am wondering can just get the `POST' data without django forms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course you can get POST data easily by using:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST['variable']
```

where `variable` is the field name.