# Django: Get LIST data from HTML without forms or models

Tags: python, html, django, list, post

I have an HTML page with a series of list items. I would like to be able to push a button, read the data in the list, and do a sort of transformation. I thought it would be rather like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845587/get-data-from-html-without-using-django-form-template).

However, this format uses the name attribute to get the data and neither a list or list item can have names!

My HTML:

```
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ul id="myList">
        <li id="myId1">First Item</li>
        <li id="myId2">Second Item</li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My python:

```
def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    var = request.POST['myList']
    print(var)
return render(request, "test.html", {})
```

Is there a way to get items in a list?

Additional Information:

- Current output is just `None`.
- I can grab data like text boxes just fine, those are named items.
- I have tried a few other suggestions, like `var = request.POST.get('myList')`, and even started dealing with forms and
  models but I could only grab data that was IN the model that way, not a `<li>`.

Comment: Can you print the output of request.POST?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to have `input` tags with `name` attributes inside your form for it to submit any data to the server. Just sticking some list items in there will do nothing - HTML forms require inputs.

Something like this might work for you:

```
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ul id="myList">
        <li id="myId1">First Item <input type="hidden" name="mylist[]" value="myid1"></li>
        <li id="myId2">Second Item <input type="hidden" name="mylist[]" value="myid2"></li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

i.e, insert a hidden input into each item in your list, with `name` and `value` attributes, that should then result in something being available in `request.POST.getlist('mylist')`.

Comment: This worked just as I wanted, thank you for the feedback!