# How to get elements of an HTML list which were dynamically generated by JavaScript in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am currently facing an issue where I have to get the elements of an HTML List which are inside a form using Django. Below is my HTML code before JavaScript is run:

```
<form action="/" class="needs-validation" method="POST"  novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <ul class="list-group my-4">
          <li id="productListing1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            
          </li>
          <li id="productListing2" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            
          </li>
          <li id="productListing3" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            
          </li>
          <li id="cart-total-price" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
           Total: PKR-0
          </li>
</form>
```

Currently, the list is empty. After pressing a button to calculate the total, the HTML code takes the following form:

```
<ul class="list-group my-4">
          <li id="productListing1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Juice PKR-40</li>
          <li id="productListing2" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Juice PKR-40</li>
          <li id="productListing3" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Juice PKR-40</li>
          <li id="cart-total-price" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Total: PKR-120</li>
        </ul>
```

Now, I want to make Django read all these list elements. How do I do that?

**What I have tried so far:**

I tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458305/django-get-list-data-from-html-without-forms-or-models) to accomplish this task. However, when I add the hidden input tags, JavaScript cannot perform the calculations and the last element becomes:

```
<li id="cart-total-price" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Total: PKR-NaN</li>
```

I have been stuck on this simple looking problem for a day now, I will appreciate if you can help me with this!

**P.S:**

For reference, my JavaScript code used for updating the list items and calculating the total is also given below:

```
function addItemToCart(productTitle,productPricePKR)
{
  var itemListing=document.getElementsByClassName('list-group-item')
  for (var i=0;i<itemListing.length;i++)
  {
    if (itemListing[i].innerHTML.trim().length==0)
    {
      itemListing[i].innerHTML=productTitle + " " + productPricePKR
      break;
    }
  
  }
}

function cartTotal()
{
var listItems=document.getElementsByClassName('list-group-item')
var total=0
for (var i=0;i<listItems.length-1;i++)
{
  if (listItems[i].innerHTML.trim().length==0)
  {
    break;
  }

  else
  {
    var cartItemDesc=listItems[i]
    cartItemDesc=listItems[i].innerHTML
    var cartItemPrice = cartItemDesc.substring(cartItemDesc.indexOf('-') + 1);
    //console.log(cartItemPrice)
    var price=parseFloat(cartItemPrice)
    total=total+price
  }
  
  document.getElementById('cart-total-price').innerHTML="Total: PKR-" + total
}
}
```

where `productTitle` is the name of the product and `productPricePKR` is the price of the product.

**Edit:**
Upon request, I am including the view for the particular problem as well.

```
def home(request):
    items=StockManagement.objects.all()
    if request.method=='POST':
        TotalPrice=request.POST.get('TotalPrice')
        ItemsBought=request.POST.getlist('mylist')
        firstname=request.POST['firstname']
        lastname=request.POST['lastname']
        print(TotalPrice,ItemsBought,firstname,lastname)
        InsertCheckoutEntry=Checkout(TotalPrice=TotalPrice,ItemsBought=ItemsBought,firstname=firstname,lastname=lastname)
    return render(request,"Home.html",context={"items":items})
```

Comment: how do you expect django to interact with such template? with a view? can you share it as well?

Comment: @Carlo I have included that in my Edit as well.

Comment: I am not sure about that, but I may feel that the problem is that django post is clearing the form hence JS has no values to calculate and return none. While when you are not triggering the view (id missing) basically JS is just doing the sum up. I'd like to help you further but, reproduce all the steps in detail on my machine just will take too long, sorry.